# If $R$ is a integral domain and $S$ is a subring of $R$ then is $S$ an integral domain automatically?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the problem that I have:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $S$ be a subring of $R$ containing the one of $R$. Prove that $S$ is also an integral domain.

Here is my answer: Suppose for a contradiction that $S$ is not an integral domain then there exists $x,y \in S$ s.t $x,y \neq 0$ and $x \cdot y=0$ but since $S$ is a subset of $R$ then $x,y \in R$ and so $R$ is not an integral domain i.e. a contradiction. So $S$ is an integral domain.  $~\square$

My problem is why does the question stipulate that $S$ must contain the one from $R$. Why is this necessary?

Comment: Because if it doesn't have identity, its not an integral domain. Check definition. Your proof is ok

Comment: Why does it need the identity otherwise it won't be an integral domain? I don't see why this is true? My definition does say that we are talking about commutative rings with one but I'm not sure why it is necessary to make sure that is the case.

Comment: What is an integral domain? A: a ring with soma special properties. One of the properties is the one just proved. Another one is that it contains an identity element. General rings need not have one

Comment: Well my definition is: Let R be a commutative ring with one then R is an ID if there isn't two non zero elements that can multiply to give zero. But I don't see why we have to stipulate that we are talking about commutative rings with one. Wouldn't this definition make sense in any ring?

Comment: So, as you said, before checking this extra property, you need a commutative with identity ring. If $S$ does not have identity, there's nothing to talk about

Comment: Yes; the definition would make sense, but it is not the definition. Desirable properties come with all these conditions together

Comment: A fun thing to do is to create your Matt-rings with the property described and try to find cool properties. As why we don't usually consider this is that identity and commutaticity are much more elementary properties. So we start w rings commutative and go refining properties til we get an object that is fully understood. And then go backwards

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't even have to stipulate that $1_S=1_R$ as long as you do stipulate that S does have a nonzero identity: it can then be proven that R and S share identity.

This is because any nonzero idempotent element of a ring without nonzero zero divisors is automatically the identity of the ring.

However, requiring a subring to share the identity of the containing ring is a standard thing to do, and sidesteps having to think about the path I just outlined. integral domains "without identity" are not usually called integral domains.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the convention that all rings have $1$, and that subrings necessarily contain the $1$ of the larger ring.

Under these conventions, the definition of an integral domain is that its a commutative ring $R$ satisfying the following two conditions:

- For all $x,y \in R$, we have $xy = 0 \rightarrow x = 0 \vee y = 0$.
- $1_R \neq 0_R.$

Now, your proof is basically correct. But you haven't checked that $1_S \neq 0_S$. Of course, this is kind of trivial, since $1_S = 1_R$ and $0_S = 0_R$, by the definition of "subring."

Answer (score 2):

Rings (should) always have an identity; otherwise call them pseudo-rings or rngs or non-unital rings. Subrings are injective ring homomorphisms, and of course ring homomorphisms preserve (by definition) the whole structure, including the unit. This is no special convention - it follows from general principles of general algebra.

Comment: I should add that I completely agree with this answer. Although from the limited perspective of ring theory, "ring homomorphisms preserve unity" is merely one of many possibly conventions, from the broader and more enlightened viewpoint of universal algebra, "ring homomorphisms preserve unity" is automatic, and not really a convention at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have also upvoted your answer.